# z-index and positioning different in FF9

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position

Can you tell what I am doing wrong with the menu buttons? It works on IE8 and chrome but not in FF (9). I presume I've messed up something with positioning and z-index.

[link to the site](http://nagomedia.blackflow.pl)

Thanks.

Edit. It doesn't work on any FF and IE7.

Comment: Well, how is it supposed to work? I don't use anything other than Firefox, sorry.

Comment: oh, price tags should be over the page. Now they float right for some reason:)

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot of the right vs the wrong views?

Comment: It's not `z-index` what's wrong there, it's the main concept of your page style. You're positioning absolute elements presuming them to be relative positioned to floating elements... that is a wrong thing to do and ends up in problems like this one.

Comment: Try setting `left` css property to every one of your menu images... and add `position:relative` to the parent div, just as @Deadlykipper says in its answer

Comment: with relative positioning it looks like this.http://nagomedia.blackflow.pl/index3.html

Comment: the add the property `top:0` to the elements inside the div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without downloading the site and playing with it myself, it's a bit tricky to work it out. But, I'd try adding `position: relative;` to div.content and then adjusting your `img.menu(x)` by setting `left: NNNpx;`.

Also, I don't understand why you use `position:absolute;` on the img tags when you're not using `top` or `left` attributes to set the position. Without a surrounding div with `position:relative`, the img tags will be referencing the absolute position of the entire window not the containing div.

Comment: +1 The structure is kinda weird to accomplish the end goal, but without changing the core of the approach, he will definitely need to be setting positional information (top/bottom/left/right) to make use of the absolute positioning, that's for sure!

Comment: When I change them to relative it all falls apart- no idea why. Adding left attribute to img.menu instead of margin dose the job. I don't know why, but I always thought that that using absolute positioning instead of floats was "not the most elegant way"...;D

Comment: @Greg Pettit- Do you have an idea how to do it any other way?

Comment: Michal, floating your container div's is fine, but if you are using absolute positioning, the element being positioned needs to be inside a div that has the style `position:relative;`, othewise it will take the edges of the entire window, not the container.

Comment: @Michal, without an exhaustive investigation, my first impulse is that if you want the tags and the hanging paper to share the same space, absolute positioning is fine but the tags should be within the paper ('main', but this is somewhat unsemantic, since a 'menu' probably shouldn't be inside a 'main') or put them both into a shared wrapper container of some sort. Then follow Deadlykipper's advice about making the wrapping container have relative positioning for your absolutely-positioned tags.

Answer (score 0):

Validate your html that list of errors. First thing noticed, id names must be unique to one element on a page. Also, make sure you are using FF or Chrome as your reference browser.

Comment: @MichałKorzeniowski - Invalid markup is hardly "cosmetics" and can break your page, especially with id names. Glad you fixed it. I'm moving and don't have FF on this laptop to look further into this.